# How to make HttpClient stops processing

Tags: java, httpclient

I have a strange issue and I can't find the solution.
I have the following code for building my ClosableHttpClient :

```java
private void createClient() {
  int timeout = 5;
  RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setConnectTimeout(timeout * 1000)
    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout * 1000)
    .setSocketTimeout(timeout * 1000).build();
  
  final SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    final HostnameVerifier defaultHostnameVerifier = SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
    final SSLConnectionSocketFactory systemSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(socketFactory, defaultHostnameVerifier);
    httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(systemSocketFactory)
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
        .build();       
}
```

and than I'm trying this:

```java
private JSONObject sendPostRequest(String url, StringEntity postData) throws HttpException, IOException {
  HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
  for (String key : headers.keySet()) {
    request.addHeader(key, headers.get(key));
  }
  request.setEntity(postData);

  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

  int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

  if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    return new JSONObject(content);
  } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
    throw new HttpException("Autorisierung nicht möglich");
  }
  throw new HttpException(String.valueOf(statusCode));
}
```

the code stops at httpclient.execute(). And I mean it stops. There is nothing after, no log no stacktrace nothing. When I try my code on localhost ther is the following debug-log

```
[2022-02-11T09:29:10] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies:123 - CookieSpec selected: default
[2022-02-11T09:29:10] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache:77 - Auth cache not set in the context
[2022-02-11T09:29:10] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:267 - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://doesnt.matter:8443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
[2022-02-11T09:29:10] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:312 - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://doesnt.matter:8443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[2022-02-11T09:29:10] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec:234 - Opening connection {s}->https://doesnt.matter:8443
[2022-02-11T09:29:10] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:139 - Connecting to doesnt.matter/1.2.1.8:8443
[2022-02-11T09:29:10] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:366 - Connecting socket to doesnt.matter/1.2.1.8:8443 with timeout 5000
[2022-02-11T09:29:10] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:430 - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.2]
[2022-02-11T09:29:10] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:431 - Enabled cipher suites:[SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
[2022-02-11T09:29:10] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:435 - Starting handshake
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:465 - Secure session established
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:466 -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:467 -  negotiated cipher suite: SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:475 -  peer principal: CN=doesnt.matter, OU=D100, OU=SSL Server, OU=SSL, O=Finanz Informatik, C=DE
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:484 -  peer alternative names: [doesnt.matter]
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:488 -  issuer principal: CN=Finanz Informatik Issuing CA 01, OU=PKI, O=Finanz Informatik, C=DE
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:146 - Connection established 16.160.132.187:58678<->17.239.174.83:8443
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:88 - http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 5000
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec:255 - Executing request POST /rest-api/authenticate HTTP/1.1
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec:260 - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec:266 - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:133 - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /rest-api/authenticate HTTP/1.1
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 88
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: doesnt.matter:8443
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_291)
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /rest-api/authenticate HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 88[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: doesnt.matter:8443[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_291)[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:87 - http-outgoing-0 >> "{"clientContext":1,"password":"*********","repository":"UCMDB","username":"******"}"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Fri, 11 Feb 2022 08:29:10 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "X-FRAME-OPTIONS: [\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Cache-Control: no-store[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "IE-Language: en[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers , Authorization, Cache-Control, Pragma, Expires[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Access-Control-Max-Age: 17200[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=node01dumaqs3jy4ycc2vtykxc0btx188; HttpOnly; secure; path=/rest-api[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 243[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "{[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "  "token" : "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfc2FsdCI6IlY5OTBTVFdNVlFPUkEwMSIsImV4cCI6MTY0NDU3MTc1MCwicmVwb3NpdG9yeSI6IlVDTURCIiwiY3VzdG9tZXIiOjEsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoic3lzYWRtaW4ifQ.-BzMAsqUT0FdEpMsf0M__FodAP3yv7JOelXMvzwQBK4"[\r][\n]"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.wire:87 - http-outgoing-0 << "}"
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:122 - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Fri, 11 Feb 2022 08:29:10 GMT
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << X-FRAME-OPTIONS: 
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Cache-Control: no-store
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << IE-Language: en
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers , Authorization, Cache-Control, Pragma, Expires
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Max-Age: 17200
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=node01dumaqs3jy4ycc2vtykxc0btx188; HttpOnly; secure; path=/rest-api
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/json
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 243
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec:285 - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies:119 - Cookie accepted [JSESSIONID="node01dumaqs3jy4ycc2vtykxc0btx188", version:0, domain:doesnt.matter, path:/rest-api, expiry:null]
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:344 - Connection [id: 0][route: {s}->https://doesnt.matter:8443] can be kept alive indefinitely
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:88 - http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:351 - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://doesnt.matter:8443][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:411 - Connection manager is shutting down
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:79 - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:434 - Connection manager shut down
```

When I deploy it to the WLP Server I only get the following output

```
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies:123 - CookieSpec selected: default
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache:77 - Auth cache not set in the context
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:267 - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://doesnt.matter:8443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:312 - Connection leased: [id: 120][route: {s}->https://doesnt.matter:8443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec:234 - Opening connection {s}->https://doesnt.matter:8443
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:139 - Connecting to doesnt.matter/1.2.1.8:8443
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:366 - Connecting socket to doesnt.matter/1.2.1.8:8443 with timeout 5000
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:430 - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.2]
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:431 - Enabled cipher suites:[SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:435 - Starting handshake
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Finalizer thread] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:411 - Connection manager is shutting down
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Finalizer thread] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:434 - Connection manager shut down
[2022-02-11T09:26:23] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:411 - Connection manager is shutting down
[2022-02-11T09:26:23] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:96 - http-outgoing-120: Shutdown connection
[2022-02-11T09:26:23] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:434 - Connection manager shut down
```

And as I said than there is nothing. My code stops proceeding. This test is made every 15 Minutes and it is in a for-next-loop with some other tests. If it wold send an exception the for-next could work on, but it only stops working. Can someone tell my why it only stops and doesn't send something back to the application and help me making it stop so the other tasks are run.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see between your LocalHost vs your Client connection is the following:

```
[2022-02-11T09:29:10] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:435 - Starting handshake
[2022-02-11T09:29:11] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-2] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:465 - Secure session established
```

While for your client:

```
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Default Executor-thread-576] apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:435 - Starting handshake
[2022-02-11T09:25:50] [DEBUG] [Finalizer thread] apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:411 - Connection manager is shutting down
```

You could be facing 2 issues:

- You are on a server which has network firewall of some kind, which does not allow you to access the specific IP you are attempting to reach, therefore the connection is getting killed instantly.
- Another issue might be that your SSL connection for that IP is invalid, however I think this is less likely, because if there is a problem in SSL, you could get some debug info regarding that.

Comment: Hi, I think I have alle FW ports open, that should by open. But if I'm wrong shouldn't there be an exception that the host can't be reached?

Comment: Not if the server you are on kills the connection, you can see in the console that it is telling you the `Connection manager is shutting down`  So something is killing it from the machine you are on.   This is my guess @DanielBecker

Comment: Okay, then how can I check this. Could it make sense to put all processes in seperate threads and check if the thread is running?

Comment: @DanielBecker Could you check if you have SSL Enabled in WSL? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=liberty-enabling-ssl-communication-in

Comment: transportSecurity-1.0 is enabled and jsse-2.1.0 is in the classpath if that makes any difference